# TCP High Send-q coupled with FIN_WAIT1 status

Tags: tcp, netstat, packetloss

I'm having a problem with one of my webservers, which is taking minutes to completely render a web page.

I had a look at the TCP connection and noticed that I have a very high value in the send-q buffer, while also having a TCP state of FIN_WAIT1, which sugests TCP has initiated an active close while data is still in the buffers?

Looking at my network interface, I also noticed a high number of dropped packets. So the send-q could be the attempt to re-transmit these packets?

The page eventually does load and the send-q goes down to zero, with the TCP connection closing.

I just wondered if anyone had encountered this before, and that I'm on the 'right lines' so to speak.

Comment: Packet loss is always a problem, so you should check the network connection on your server.